# How to know if a particle spins clockwise or counterclockwise?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If I am given the position vector of a particle at any time, how can I know if the particle spins clockwise or counterclockwise?

**UPDATE:** Maybe I should have said that the particle is moving in cirlces.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the normal vector to the parameetrization, call it $\vec n$. Then if $\det(\vec i,\vec j,\vec n)>0$, the basis $\vec i,\vec j,\vec n$ is oriented as the standard basis $\vec i, \vec j, \vec k$, and your particle spins "positively", namely counterclockwise.  If $\det(\vec i,\vec j,\vec n)<0$, the same reasoning means the particle spins clockwise. If $\det(\vec i,\vec j,\vec n)=0$, it spins parallel to the $xz$-plane. Notice that the determinant's sign is determined by the sign of the $z$ coordinate of $n$.

Edit: To adress the question edit: Observe that this reasoning is independent of the particle spinning in circles, and gives a generalized sense of "clockwise" (so really, it doesn't matter if it spins in circles or not).